# RoR: select join model by condition on child table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got the following schema:

```
foo:
  id: integer

bar:
  id: integer
  condition: boolean

foo_bar:
  id: integer
  foo_id: integer
  bar_id: integer
```

Both model and schema look like this. Given an instance of foo, I'd like to get an instance of foo_bar where the corresponding bar.condition is true.

Is there a RoR-friendly way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to setup some ActiveRecord associations:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars
end

class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar
end
```

Then you can query those associations.  Given an instance of Foo, find the first instance of FooBar where bar.name == 'my-bar':

```
foo = Foo.find(1)
foo.foo_bars.include(:bar).where(bar: {name: 'my-bar'}).first
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to consider [**ActiveRecord Association Extensions**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
#app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :foo_bar
   has_many :bar, through: :foo_bar do
      def true
         where condition: true
      end
   end
end

#app/models/foo_bar.rb
class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :foo
   belongs_to :bar
end

#app/models/bar.rb
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :foo_bar
   has_many :foo, through: :foo_bar
end
```

This will give you the ability to call the following:

```
@foo = Foo.find x
@foo.bar.true
```

Although this won't call the `foo_bar` records themselves, if you work it correctly, you *should* be able to load the data you require

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but ultimately not what I'm looking for. I need a single instance of the join model that satisfies the condition. I care less about `bar` than I do about `foo_bar`